# uploading large files (1-2GB to sharepoint) via ASP.NET core web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying create an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application - hosted in Azure - that will allow end users to upload large files to a list in Sharepoint.

From what I've been reading, when dealing with large files, it's best not to buffer but create a stream and write it directory to the the API / final destination. ?

I'm new to both Sharepoint dev, (even as a user... don't use it very much) .NET / .Net Core.
But I found this example

`https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/mvc/models/file-uploads/samples/3.x/SampleApp`

Specifically I've been poking around the "Streamed Single File Upload with AJAX (Physical)" logic provided in the application.

My line of thinking is:

a) Figure out how to get the file from the end user onto my server... in chunks - which is what I think this sample is doing.

b) try to send these chunks to sharepoint.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/large-file-upload?tabs=csharp

But I would like someone with more experience just to vet my thinking / the approach.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0#upload-large-files-with-streaming) to learn how it works and the Multipart body length limit: *Within the action, the form's contents are read using a MultipartReader, which reads each individual MultipartSection, processing the file or storing the contents as appropriate. After the multipart sections are read, the action performs its own model binding.*

Comment: Since you want to upload file to SharePoint, you could [try to use a provider-hosted add-in to upload large files to SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/upload-large-files-sample-app-for-sharepoint).